# Why there's an error in CONVERT Query in PHP MyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, sql

Can you please check this if there's something wrong? I am sure that there's nothing wrong with the query but I don't know why it shows this error.
This is my query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(15),'9:30',100)
```

[image]

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: That looks like a Sql Server function call. PHPMyAdmin consoles tend to talk to MySql databases, rather than Sql Server, which is corroborated by the error message and tags. The [syntax for the MySQL version of the convert function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_convert.asp) is a little different from Sql Server.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn so is there's something that can solve it?

Comment: Yes. Follow the documentation for the MySql `CONVERT()` function. I'd give you an example, but its not at all clear what you're trying to do, since this sample code is trying to convert another varchar literal into a varchar, which is meaningless.